# Invalid return character or leading space in header: Authorization // - Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

So I have a method trying to do a function call and the whole thing requires a base64 encoded key and secret

I have a class method thats trying to so the right stuff and make the call but im getting an error

My method as follows:

```py
# Build the connection string
        connection_string = f'{self.org_id}:{rr_key}:{rr_secret}'
        connection_string = connection_string.encode("ascii")
        logging.info(f'Connection string to be encoded: {connection_string}')

        # Base 64 encode the file
        base64encode = base64.encodestring(connection_string)
        logging.info(f'Base 64 string to send: Basic {base64encode.decode("utf-8")}')

        # Fetch the token from API
        encoded_string = base64encode.decode("utf-8")
        encoded_string = encoded_string.replace('\r', '')
        fetch_token = requests.post(f'{self.url}/oauth/token',
                                    headers={'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded_string}'},
                                    data={"grant_type": "client_credentials"})
```

And the error on return is

```
File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/kojo-backend-app-tMeByA0R/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 515, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/kojo-backend-app-tMeByA0R/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 443, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/kojo-backend-app-tMeByA0R/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 319, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/kojo-backend-app-tMeByA0R/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 453, in prepare_headers
    check_header_validity(header)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/kojo-backend-app-tMeByA0R/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 1025, in check_header_validity
    raise InvalidHeader("Invalid return character or leading space in header: %s" % name)
requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Invalid return character or leading space in header: Authorization
```

I have tried various ways of doing whats needed but I feel the b'' around the string is the issue hence why i decoded to UTF-8.

Any suggestions would be super welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your troubles is the use of `base64.encodestring`. According to the documentation, it'll split the data in **lines** of base64 data, hence the presence of the newline characters.

Prefer using `b64encode` et `b64decode` directly, they do not do this magic

```py
## Preamble to reproduce the problem
import logging
import base64
import requests

org_id = "toto_org"
rr_key = "key"
rr_secret = "secret"

# Build the connection string
connection_string = f'{org_id}:{rr_key}:{rr_secret}'
connection_string = connection_string.encode("ascii")
logging.info(f'Connection string to be encoded: {connection_string}')

# Base 64 encode the file
## ! I changed the method used here
base64encode = base64.b64encode(connection_string)
logging.info(f'Base 64 string to send: Basic {base64encode.decode("utf-8")}')

# Fetch the token from API
# ! ascii codec is sufficient here, your data is in base64 format
encoded_string = base64encode.decode('ascii')

fetch_token = requests.post(f'http://localhost/oauth/token',
                        headers={'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded_string}'},
                        data={"grant_type": "client_credentials"})
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thank you! Saved me a huge headache!