# Python - Is there a way to bypass illegal characters in dictionary keys?

Tags: python, python-requests

I was wondering if there was a way to bypass illegal characters in dictionary keys?

I am making a "Famous Birthdays" boost faker, essentially a bot that keeps hitting the Famous Birthdays api to make it look like someone boosted the profile the person chooses. I pulled the API from clicking the "Boost" button while on the Network tab in inspect element.

Here are the dictionary keys in question:

```
':authority': 'www.famousbirthdays.com',
':method': 'POST',
':path': '/api/people/boost',
':scheme': 'https',
```

When I run my program, it throws an error telling me that I need to remove the illegal characters in question.

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: 
Invalid leading whitespace, reserved character(s), or returncharacter(s) in header name: ':authority'
```

Is there anyway to bypass this? The illegal characters cannot be removed because they pertain to the headers, and if I change the headers, it will break the program.

EDIT: Here is my code so it is easier to solve the issue:

```
#https://www.famousbirthdays.com/api/people/boost
import requests
from hyper.contrib import HTTP20Adapter
def main():
  person = input('Insert page link (e.g kristian-ramey)\n')
  def getHeaders(person):
    global headers
    headers = {
      ':authority': 'www.famousbirthdays.com',
      ':method': 'POST',
      ':path': '/api/people/boost',
      ':scheme': 'https',
      'accept': '*/*',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7',
      'content-length': '23',
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'cookie': '__aaxsc=1; _ga=GA1.2.1274875939.1657675345; _gid=GA1.2.109078920.1657675345; lookup=las+vegas; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InZvNmdIXC9hSmhPRzZVelpRMVwvNUV4Zz09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJrbGJYZWloaUpjbnp4cVFCXC8xSndoSmxudmxLbjU5aG9cL2NCWW5qSWVWZ0lJZjVZbzY3ZWRwWlI3ZFZiTnJLZHYiLCJtYWMiOiJkYWViNjNlZmIxODc1ZTllOWM5OGEzMmM0ZTkxMGMzODA2ZTA4MDMyODQ1OWFjYzA4MzQyNDgzMmZjNjQ4ODY0In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ino1QkR6TTBGaU1kSFBhSjZNMUhMWFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicFwvaVh0TUpReWxmS0pJVzVsV3JzUUlBOGpUKzYySjlwcEdzcTN1ZTlLNUVTenpqazFuZkRsa2xBNWFRT0JRbnkiLCJtYWMiOiJlZDhlODBhMTVjOTYxYzRlZDAxM2JhMGZjYzVkMWE0NmY0NGQyOTkwMmIwNWJhMmNmYmEyYzc0MGVhYTU3OWYzIn0%3D; aasd=8%7C1657676628018',
      'origin': 'https://www.famousbirthdays.com',
      'referer': f'https://www.famousbirthdays.com/people/{person}.html',
      'sec-ch-ua': "\".Not/A)Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"103\", \"Chromium\";v=\"103\"",
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
      'sec-ch-ua-platform': "\"Windows\"",
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
      }
    return headers
  session = requests.session() 
  session.mount('http://www.famousbirthdays.com/api/people/boost', HTTP20Adapter())
  r = session.post('http://www.famousbirthdays.com/api/people/boost',headers=getHeaders(person))
  print(r.text)
  print(r.status_code)
main()
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116384/invalid-return-character-or-leading-space-in-header-authorization-python

Comment: @Abhishek I saw this and didn't really know what to make of it, considering it was base64 and that didn't apply to my situation.

Comment: Looks to me like the four headers that are giving you problems (the ones with leading colons) aren't necessary at all. When you call `session.post` with the URL specified, you're already providing all the info that those headers contains. Try making requests without those headers and see if it works.

Comment: @schwartz721 Definitely does not work. {"errors":{"url":"Missing param url"},"page":"1","offset":0,"status":"error"}

Comment: @schwartz721 Then again I might just have to pass the url and just the url.

Comment: @schwartz721 tried that, didn't work :(

Comment: Could be that the site is expecting some Authentication that you don't have. But at the very least, your request needs to include the same payload as the one you're trying to mimic.

Comment: @schwartz721 It definitely has the same payload, only other thing I'm noticing in the Network tab is that the request is coming from a specific proxy, my last idea is to try that proxy and see if the request will work, but my current problem is that the requests module won't accept my HTTP2/0 headers

Comment: In the code you posted, your POST request doesn't have any payload/body, just URL and headers. The POST request that you're mimicking has Form-Data `url: person-name.html`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) method

```py
raw_dict = {':authority': 'www.famousbirthdays.com', ':method': 'POST',}
good_dict = {item.lstrip(":"):value for item, value in q.items()}
print(good_dict)
```

The output is:

```
{'authority': 'www.famousbirthdays.com', 'method': 'POST'}
```

Comment: does this still contain the : that is required?

Comment: Oh, sorry. But Python can proccess "illegal chracters". So error is out of there. Without your code nobody can get an advice.

Comment: I posted my code so you can see what i am doing wrong